# How to manage playerIds with SignalR and MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr, persistence

In game development with `SignalR` and `MVC`, I have to manage the player id's.

With `MVC` all `Controllers` is re created for each `AJAX` request so you can't store anything unless you use a database or store it in a cookie.

Does `SignalR` have any tools I can use for persisting something like `playerIds` for a game to ease it the situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the connection id's from SignalR, but you can register a ID per user on the `OnConnected` method. just override that function in your hub.

There might be a simpler way to do it, but one option is to pass the session key to JS, and from JS you can pass that session key (or any other unique identifier) back to the server on every command.

For example, while the user is first connected: OnConnected() -> gets the user unique id from JS and saves it locally to map each user to a unique id(possibly save that id as a group id so you can call send back msgs to that user according to the id).
After you that on each request sent to the hub you can attach the unique ID to it and then you can use it however you like.

I'm pretty sure you can find easier way to define a unique identifier and maybe a more suitable way to save your data in the hub.

Now that I think about it, you should also check [this](https://github.com/ntaylormullen/shootr).